# Form validation for appendChild

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created add rows form by using `appendChild`.

Whenever I click `addrow` button a row is formed but form validations are not applying for that row. And now I need validation for all rows.  Please recommend a method.

**I need validations for all other addon rows**

```js
var counter = 0;
var limit = 0 / 0;
function addInput(dynamicInput) {
    if (counter == limit) {
        alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
    }
    else {
        var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
        newdiv.innerHTML = "<br>User:" + " <input type='text' name='user' id='user'> " +
    "Age:" + " <input type='number' name='Age'> " +
    "Qualify:" + " <input type='text' name='qualification' id='qual'> " +
    "Specilztn:" + " <input type='text' name='specialization' id='spec'> " +
    "Percentage:" + " <input type='number' name='percentage' id='perc'> " +
    " <input type='submit' id='subtn2'>";

        document.getElementById(dynamicInput).appendChild(newdiv);
        counter++;
        document.getElementById("removerow").style.display = "block";
    }
}


function removeInput() {
    var x = document.getElementById("dynamicInput");
    if (x.hasChildNodes()) {
        x.removeChild(x.childNodes[14]);
    }
}

function formvalidation() {

    var a = document.getElementById("user");
    var b = document.getElementById("age");
    var c = document.getElementById("qual");
    var d = document.getElementById("spec");
    var e = document.getElementById("perc");

    if (uservalidation()) {
        if (agevalidation()) {
            if (qualvalidation()) {
                if (specvalidation()) {
                    if (percvalidation()) {

                    }
                    else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }

    function uservalidation() {
        if (a.value == "") {
            document.getElementById("uerr").innerHTML = "Enter UserName";
            document.getElementById("user").focus();
            return false;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("uerr").style.visibility = "hidden";
            return true;
        }
    }
    function agevalidation() {
        if (b.value == "") {
            document.getElementById("agerr").innerHTML = "Enter  Age";
            document.getElementById("age").focus();
            return false;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("agerr").style.visibility = "hidden";
            return true;
        }
    }

    function qualvalidation() {
        if (c.value == "") {
            document.getElementById("qerr").innerHTML = "Enter Qualification";
            document.getElementById("qual").focus();
            return false;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("qerr").style.visibility = "hidden";
            return true;
        }
    }

    function specvalidation() {
        if (d.value == "") {
            document.getElementById("sperr").innerHTML = "Enter Specialization";
            document.getElementById("spec").focus();
            return false;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("sperr").style.visibility = "hidden";
            return true;
        }
    }

    function percvalidation() {
        var addrowbtn = document.getElementById("addrow");
        if (e.value == "") {
            document.getElementById("pererr").innerHTML = "Enter Percentage";
            document.getElementById("perc").focus();

            return false;

        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("pererr").style.visibility = "hidden";

            addrowbtn.style.display = "block";

        }
    }
}
```

```css
b{
    color:red;
}
#form2{
    display:none;
}
#addrow{
    display:none;
    /* float:right;
        margin-top:20px;
        margin-right:45px; */
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    right: 75px;
    background:green;
    color:white;
    cursor:pointer;   
} 
#removerow{
    display:none;
    background:red;
    color:white;
    cursor:pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" id="form1" name="form1" onsubmit="return formvalidation()">
    <div id="dynamicInput">
        User: <input type="text" name="user" id="user">
        Age:  <input type="number" name="age" id="age">
        Qualify: <input type="text" name="qualification" id="qual">
        Specilztn:<input type="text" name="specialization" id="spec">
        Percentage:<input type="number" name="percentage" id="perc">
        <input type="submit" id="sbtn">


        <p>
            <b id="uerr"> </b>
            <b id="agerr"> </b>
            <b id="qerr"> </b>
            <b id="sperr"> </b>
            <b id="pererr"> </b>
        </p>

    </div>
    <input type="button" value="Add Row" id="addrow" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');">
    <input type="button" value="Del Row" id="removerow" onClick="removeInput();">
</form>
```

Comment: Removed tag from title

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems here. Here's a few tips:

1) When you are creating your new div, you aren't giving it an id, so your validation will never find it.

```
 var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
 newdiv.setAttribute("id", "Div1"); // you can generate the id from your counter
```

2) All of your validations are static so there aren't any validations on your new div, so now even though we just gave it an id, there's no logic to find it. Your validation doesn't know anything about the new div at all. You can add some validations using your new id:

```
var div1 = document.getElementById("Div1");
if(div1){ 
// ... validation logic 
}
```

3) Another thing about your validation - it doesn't need to be that complicated. You  have too many inner functions doing too many things. Doing JUST this for each of your validations in your formvalidation function would be a little cleaner, at least:

```
var user = document.getElementById("user");
if(!user){
        document.getElementById("uerr").innerHTML = "Enter UserName";
        document.getElementById("user").focus();
        return false;
 } else {
        document.getElementById("uerr").style.visibility = "hidden";
 }
```

Comment: Hi Michael, I am unable to understand how to write validation logic inside if(div1){ ......}.

Comment: it would look similar to your existing validation, but with your dynamic id and a new dynamic validation tag or something like that. I think you could just do `div1.focus(); return false;` or something like that if you don't want to make a new validation tag. 

also, div1 is just an example, you would loop through the dynamically created elements and use their new ids.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what application you're writing, but whenever you actually run the validation function, you will check if it returned false.

Comment: Did this help you?